# Determine electromagnet inductance

Tags: inductance, coil, electromagnet

I am trying to measure the inductance of a large electromagnetic brake (coil diameter 34cm).
I used two methods:

- LCR meter (100Hz because the brake is activated using a rectified 50Hz AC voltage) (UNI-T UT612)
- Mathematical calculation using current waveform

The LCR meter results are as follows. Series equivalent mode measurements are advised for impedances below 100Ohm. I added the parallel measurement for reference:

- Ls = 1.654 H
- Lp = 2.814 H
- DC resistance (measured using multimeter) = 35.2Ohm
- ESR (measured using LCR meter) = 939Ohm

i analzed the current waveform according to the formulas shown in the figure below:
[image]

The formula to calculate the coil charging current waveform is:

- iL(t) = Imax(1-e^-t(R/L))

I measured the coil current during activation of the brake.
Screenshot of my measurements:
[image]

The maximum current is 5.7A as can be seen on the oscilloscope screenshot (measured using 0.2Ohm shunt) The 1 timeconstant current is:

- IL(L/R) = Imax(1-e^-1) = 3.6A

Using the current waveform the measured time to reach 3.6A is 0.48s
This results in an inductance of:

- L = t * R = 0.48 * 35.2 = 17H

The small 'notch' in the current waveform is caused by the armature plate getting attracted to the coil body resulting in an inductance change.

If i extrapolate the linear section before the 'notch' the time constant is around 0.43 resulting in an induction of 15H. This confirms the inductance change but seems still too high to me.

Can someone please explain why the calculated inductance value is completely different from the measured value? Why is the measured ESR 939 Ohm and the DC resistance 35.2Ohm? And which method is the best for determining the inductance?

Comment: Have you tried using the measurement meter when the brake is mechanically forced into the other direction?

Comment: I would trust the time constant value more than the LCR meter. The time constant value also gives you a value that applies over a larger range of bias currents.

Comment: @tobalt i agree on that but 17H seems way too high to me.

Comment: Well if you consider only the part to the right of the jump, the TC is more like 240 ms, which brings L down to 8 H.. This is not unlikely IMO, you probably have something like an ~100mm diameter core with a tiny air gap and 1000s of windings.

Comment: That seems like a more reasonable value. It's a fact that the inductance changes when the armature gets attracted but going from 17H at max airgap (+/- 1.3mm) to 8H at 0 airgap seems like a big jump. I also don't understand why the LCR meter can't measure this properly.

Comment: When the airgap closes, one would also expect L to go up.. I havent had much luck with such magnets and LCR meters. But I am not familiar enough with how they measure. If you want an independent value: Take a large foil capacitor and charge it to its rated voltage, then short it to the magnet and observe the ringing frequency. It's best to short it using a proper switch because otherwise there could be sparking

Comment: i also did a lt spice simulation using an R(35.2), L(17) and full bride rectifier. It confirms the time constant obtained from the measurements suggesting or 'confirming'  the coil inductance is in fact 17H (without airgap influence).  However i am still suspicious and a 3th measurement would be  best to get an independent value.

Comment: "DC resistance (measured using multimeter) = 35.2Ohm". Your resistance and current measurements suggest a power supply voltage of 35.2 X 5.7 = 200V (on load). If these numbers don't line up maybe the resistance is off. Do you know how accurate your multimeter resistance measurements are, with large series inductance? Some DMMs use dynamic resistance measurement methods which are upset when there are large C or L also in circuit.

Comment: @GeBJT The power supply voltage is an AC rectified voltage with Vavg 210V. This suggests the resistance measurement is reliable (with some margin on current/voltage measurement error) i am using an Fluke 179 multimeter so i expect the resistance measurement to be right (as the calculation confirms).